# Cannot view age restricted content using YouTube Android Player API

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Using Youtube android player api my app doesn't play age restricted videos, it just shows the message **"Sign in to confirm age"**
I am signed in to the YouTube App with an account which is age verified, I expect the video should play based on the account signed in  youtube app via YouTube Android Player API.

Using this tutorial in [making android app](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/06/simple-example-using-youtube-android.html)  it works good with non-restrict video but if i want to play a video that has age restriction it will show this error "Sign in to confirm age"

```
for example this age restricted youtube video id:
```

- zKovmts2KSk
- CrtwqDt0IEk
- ZMAbpoolm_s
- SumIZb6qMJw
- QIgx0vPPDtA
- wYGoFH6bWXg

**MainActivity.java**

```
 package com.example.androidyoutubeapiplayer;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

 public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCe6tORd9Ch4lx-9Ku5SQ476uS9OtZYsWA";
 public static final String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }

 @Override
 public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
   YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    "onInitializationFailure()", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 @Override
 public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
   boolean wasRestored) {
  if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
      }
 }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="http://android-er.blogspot.com/"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web" />

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidyoutubeapiplayer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidyoutubeapiplayer.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!!**

Answer (score 1):

[Not possible to view age restricted content with YouTube Android Player API](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4012)

same problem!

I tried it and found out that you can't add youtube link and video if its not your content.

Answer (score 0):

You are signed into your YouTube account with your credentials, but the API_KEY you have provided in your app is not yours.  Generate an API key for you here: https://console.developers.google.com

It would be a good idea to look at Oauth 2.0 if you plan to release a public app that uses YouTube API.  See [here.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Installed_Applications_Flow)

Comment: the code above is just an example ofcourse I generated my own API key but it doesn't work with age restricted video.About the Oauth 2.0 there is no proper code provided on how to use it in android youtube player API.